# WPF DispatcherTimer Memory Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

Edit: If useful, this project is on GitHub at https://github.com/lostchopstik/BetterBlync

I am building an application for the Blync status light using their provided API. This application polls the Lync/Skype for Biz client and converts the status to the appropriate light color. All aspects thus far work as expected, however when I leave this program running for an extended period of time, the memory usage grows until a System.OutOfMemory exception occurs.

I have narrowed the problem down to the DispatcherTimer holding the timer in memory and preventing it from being GCed. After reading some things online I found you could manually call for garbage collection, but this is bad practice. Regardless, here is what I have in my code right now:

```
private void initTimer()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 200 );
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler( Timer_Tick );
        timer.Start();
    }

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if any new lights are connected
        blync.FindBlyncLights();

        // Get current status from Lync client
        lync.GetStatus();

        // Change to new color
        setStatusLight();

        if ( count++ == 100 )
        {
            count = 0;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

The timer ticks every 200ms. I commented out all methods inside the timer and just let it run empty, and it still burned memory.

I am wondering what the proper way to handle this timer is. I've used the DispatcherTimer in the past and not had this issue.

I would also be open to trying something besides the DispatcherTimer.

If it is also useful, I have been messing with MemProfiler and here as my current graph with manual GC:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCf5I.jpg
[image: memory graph]

Comment: It looks like the functions that are called in the tick allocate a lot of strings. Find out how that happens and whether or not you can prevent allocating that many strings. I don't think it is related to the timer.

Comment: Also, What do you mean by burn memory? How bad is it? The screenshot shows 2 MB of managed heap. That is 'nothing'

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd That was just a snapshot right after I started it. It typically runs about 18MB at the start, and after leaving it running overnight it was at 1.6GB.

Also, if I comment out the timer.Start() the program levels off and stays at a constant memory usage instead of constant growth like the graph indicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code or the class the timer belongs to. I don't see anywhere you call Stop() on the timer. Does it need to be stopped?

You could also keep a local reference to the timer in whatever class you're in and call Start() and Stop() as needed.

If the timer never needs to be stopped and runs indefinitely, I would certainly look at what you're allocating as the timer runs and that's probably where your issue is.

Comment: If you're interested in a more detailed look, I added my github link at the top of the question.

I do not actually ever call stop because I want it to run as long as the program is running.

I'll take a closer peek and see if I can find anything.

Comment: If you've commented out everything in the tick, I would have to agree with Erno that it may not be related to the timer.